# How to get past the Subway Aeration Room in Mirrors edge

Tags: mirrors-edge

How to get past the Subway Aeration room, the room where you have to Stop the fan, and get past them before they're automatically restarted, in the Ropeburn chapter

Everytime I try, or the fan goes back on when i reach the fan (killing me), or I somehow can't reach the ledge just yet, or somehow I get to wallrun in a single place (glitch?) dropping back to the lower level afterwards.

Should I use the left (closest) or the right (away) wall (from the fan) to wallrun back to the center ledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you press the button and wallrun directly to the fans you should have plenty of time to get through them.

See [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mza2RxM98FQ#t=7m28) to see it more clearly.

Comment: managed to get past it, the critical part was to jump off the wall at the end of the wallrun.